# Merge similar object keys jquery

Tags: jquery, merge

I have similar object keys how can i merge them.

```
device_id_1:"1"
device_id_2:"2"
device_id_3:"100"
device_id_4:"10 000"
```

I could have more then 4 keys or less. Any idea how to merge/combine object keys with similar name ?

I need to combine all **device_id_X** and merge as one key **device_id**

Here i collect all input data and save to this object:

```
var data = $('#form_id').serializeArray();
var obj = {};
for (i = 0, l = data.length; i < l; i++) {
    obj[data[i].name] = data[i].value;
}
```

The **obj**  returns the object keys witch i want to merge/combine.

Comment: Do you have control over where this object is generated? It would be *far* easier to amend it there.

Comment: I have, i collect all inputs from an form and save them to this object.

Comment: In which case that's the code you need to change. Could you please edit the question to include it

Comment: @Rory McCrossan check my updated question i have pasted the object generated code.

Comment: Thank you - could you also add the HTML too. You can most likely solve this with `map()`, but how you use it depends on the HTML

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan the html is big, one `<form>` **repeated(X) times** with **many input fields**.